# How Can I Make Dynamic Query In Sequelize with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want Query Function That I can pass in FindAll Query To Get Daynamic data

Example: If I want to get data like `age>5`  then direct I can get using query paramas

This is just example

At the end I want query funcatuion that can genrate dynamic query on query params

I have made this funcation for daynamic sort, and paggination

```
const usersqquery = (q) => {
  const limit = q?.limit * 1 || 200;
  const page = q?.page * 1 || 1;
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
  const sort = q?.sort || "createdAt";
  const sortBy = q?.sortBy || "DESC";

if (q?.limit) {
    return { order: [[sort, sortBy]], limit, offset: skip };
  }
  return { order: [[sort, sortBy]] };
};
```

I want more acurate funcation for genrate dynamic query

Answer (score 1):

i've been through the same problem but in my case with **typeorm**
but i think my solution will works for you.
what i did is implement simple parser that take `stingifiedJsonObjectQuery` which is JSON string that represent **where** from client
and parse it's to **typeorm object**.
that's snippet from my production code that does the jobs:
(and please note that this is not for copy paste it just to looks at and to learn from)

```
import { BadRequestException, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Between, Equal, FindOneOptions, ILike, In, IsNull, LessThan, MoreThan } from 'typeorm';
import { ILogger } from '../../core/logger/logger.interface';
import { LOGGER_PROVIDER_NAME } from '../../core/providers.constants';
import { IQueryParser, ITypeOrmQueryParser } from './queryParser.interface';

export enum FindOperators {
  NOT = '$not',
  ILIKE = '$ilike',
  IN = '$in',
  MORE_THATN = '$MoreThan',
  LESS_THAN = '$LessThan',
  EQUAL = '$Equal',
  ISNULL = '$ISNULL',
  ARE = '$are',
  CONTAINS = '$contains',
  BETWEEN = '$between',
  Assigned = '$Assigned',
}

export interface ICondition {
  operation?: FindOperators;
  value?: any;
}

function parseOperator(condition: ICondition) {
  if (typeof condition !== 'object') return condition;
  if (condition === null || condition === undefined || condition.value == null) return IsNull();
  if (!condition.operation) return condition.value;
  switch (condition.operation) {
    case FindOperators.EQUAL:
      return Equal(condition.value);
    case FindOperators.LESS_THAN:
      return LessThan(condition.value);
    case FindOperators.MORE_THATN:
      return MoreThan(condition.value);
    case FindOperators.IN:
      return In(condition.value);
    case FindOperators.ILIKE:
      condition.value = condition.value.replace('%20', ' ');
      return ILike(condition.value);
    case FindOperators.ARE:
      return {
        id: In(condition.value),
      };
    case FindOperators.CONTAINS:
      condition.value = condition.value.replace('%20', ' ');
      return ILike('%' + condition.value + '%');
    case FindOperators.BETWEEN:
      return Between(new Date(condition.value[0]), new Date(condition.value[1]));
    default:
      throw new BadRequestException(`Operator ${condition.operation} not found`);
  }
}

function parseAndOptions(where) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(where)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      if (value['operation']) {
        where[key] = parseOperator(value);
        continue;
      }
      where[key] = parseAndOptions(value);
    }
  }
  return where;
}

function parseOrOptions(where) {
  if (Array.isArray(where)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < where.length; i++) where[i] = parseOrOptions(where[i]);
    return where;
  }

  return parseAndOptions(where);
}

function parseTypeOrmOptions(options: FindOneOptions) {
  if (options.where) options.where = parseOrOptions(options.where);
  return options;
}

export class TypeOrmQueryParser implements ITypeOrmQueryParser {
  constructor(@Inject(LOGGER_PROVIDER_NAME) private _logger: ILogger) {}

  parseQuery(str: any) {
    const result: any = str;
    try {
      result.parsedOptions = JSON.parse({ ...result }.options);
      result.options = parseTypeOrmOptions(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)).parsedOptions);
    } catch (err) {
      this._logger.error('[TYPEORM_PARSER]', 'ERROR WHILE PARSING ' + err);
      result.options = {
        where: {},
      };
    }

    result.skip = parseInt(result.skip);
    if (!result.skip) {
      result.skip = 0;
    }
    result.limit = parseInt(result.limit);
    if (!result.limit) {
      result.limit = 100;
    }

    return result;
  }
}

export class SqlQueryParser implements IQueryParser {
  parseQuery(str: any) {
    const result: any = str;
    result.skip = parseInt(result.skip);
    if (!result.skip) {
      result.skip = 0;
    }
    result.limit = parseInt(result.limit);
    if (!result.limit) {
      result.limit = 100;
    }
    if (result.options) {
      try {
        result.options = JSON.parse(result.options);
        result.options = parseTypeOrmOptions(result.options);
      } catch (err) {
        result.options = {};
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```